# Quantized fields on Schwarzschild, QNM and bound states

Tags: boundary-conditions, second-quantization, qft-in-curved-spacetime

In the process of quantization of a scalar field (in massive as in massless cases) propagating on a Schwarzschild background, we are first of all required to solve the equations of motion. Typically, we work in the tortoise coordinate, pushing the event horizon to $r_* \rightarrow \infty$, avoiding the singularity $r = 0$ and allowing an hermitian propagating operator (I guess, as it is the singularity at $r = 0$ that makes it non-hermitian, see [Sanchez 1977](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.16.937)), with respect to a standard inner product $\int_\Sigma \phi^* \psi$, $\Sigma$ being a Cauchy surface outside the horizon at $t = const$. Using the timelike Killing vector, we can find solutions of the form $e^{-i\omega t}f(r,\theta, \phi)$, and inserting this in the equations, we have in general to find the spectrum $\omega$ and the functions $f$.

We have now three types of solutions :

- $\omega \in \mathbb{R}$ : the standard asymptotic plane waves, that appear usually in the decomposition of the field (and depending on the positive frequency dependance, yield Boulware, Unruh and Hartle Hawking vacua) ;
- $\omega \in \mathbb{C}$ and requiring waves entering inside the black hole and outgoing at infinity : quasinormal modes (non-normalizable) ;
- $\omega \in \mathbb{C}$ and requiring waves entering inside the black hole and normalizable at infinity (in the massive case only) : bound states (that are actually quasibound, as they decay over time).

I guess that we don't use quasinormal modes because they don't provide normalizable wavefunctions. But what if we used the bounded modes, summing thus also over their complex frequencies ? I thought that while quantizing we should have a complete basis for solutions of the equations of motion, whereas here, bound states are not included.

Could someone help me clarify that point ?

Comment: $\omega$ is the eigenvalue of the Hamiltonian operator associated to the time evolution along the Killing time, at least in the external solution. $\omega \in \mathbb C$ means complex spectrum which is not permitted for a self-adjoint operator.

Comment: @ValterMoretti : Does this still stay true in the unbounded case ? So, the only way to see quantum mechanically the existence of resonances would be in as poles of some propagator ?

Comment: I am not an expert on resonances, sorry. What I wrote is however independent from boundedness

Comment: @ValterMoretti : I've never seen it proven in the unbounded case (not even stated clearly).

Comment: An overall comment: the approach based on modes is interesting from a physical viewpoint since it seems intuitive, but mathematically speaking, it turns out to be very difficult to use. For instance, is is very difficult (or perhaps impossible) to rigorously prove that the wanted states are Hadamard (thus the backreaction problem can be studied since the expectation value of the stress energy tensor can be renormalized) in the spacetime including the horizons. Different modern approaches are now suitable.

Comment: For a quite recent and modern review I may suggest you I.Khavkine and V. Moretti: Algebraic QFT in Curved Spacetime and quasifree Hadamard states: an introduction, Springer 2015,  arXiv:1412.5945 . Therein,  references [15] and [63] introduce modern rigorous approaches to construct Hadamard states on the Schwarzschild background.

Comment: I've noticed, but they take some time to get used to. Nevertheless, it seemed to me that to get a physical picture (relation to detectors), the mode picture was more practical.

Comment: Yes, if you are interested in the detector picture, the description by modes, is useful.

Comment: @ValterMoretti : A small question (perhaps a gigantic one in fact) :  in what way has this modern picture helped the current understanding of black holes or of some progress towards a quantum theory of gravity ?

Comment: For instance it was possible to solve, in certain cases, simultaneously the problem of evolution of the metric and the quantum matter. I do not know if in the black hole background but in the presence of light-like structure similar to horizons. A big problem solved is the validity of the Hadamard property for the Unruh state (in the massless case) and the Hartle-Hawking one (for the either massive or massless case). All the problem of UV renormalisation and general covariance has been fixed...

Comment: Sorry I have no spare time to start a chat discussion now!

Comment: I'm sorry. A last question if you allow : Are these boundary conditions we impose on the space of solutions to the equations of motion (plane waves at the asymptotics) enough to make the hamiltonian self-adjoint (first symmetric) ? Using unbounded domains is not straighforward, I have often seen that selfadjointness is assumed.

Comment: If the procedure works, the self adjointness arises easily from general results of algebraic qft.

Comment: Could you be slightly more explicit ?